# How is Velocity Template Engine used for View in Java Web Applications?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, velocity

When you have this sample code:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and you have a simple `index.jsp` file, well Tomcat will figure out this is a jsp file and it will be **translated** into a Java class first, then compiled and then it will be executed.. This is all fine.

Here, in this page: http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/06/beginning-apache-velocity-creating-a-simple-web-application/ there is a simple example/tutorial showing how velocity template engine can be used for rendering view where velocity templating language is used.

There is one thing I do not understand, in which step does the container (or the jvm?) know it should use the **Velocity Template Engine** to interpret the **`.vm`** file and do the processing on the file correctly? How does it know it is not a JSP file? Only by the extension as in JSP files?

I am not asking how the request is forwarded to the `.vm` file. I am asking when and how Velocity Engine kicks in to create the HTML from the `.vm` file using the data object we provided in the request object. Why is the .vm file not being translated into a Java Class like a jsp file? How does Tomcat decide it is not the right thing to do to try translating into a `_jsp.class` file but rather uses Velocity Template Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet` which is invoked on `*.vm` files mapped to it. First servlet is acting as a controller and dispatches to the second servlet for rendering a view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the extension is important and is used to figure out what to do, but there is nothing automagical going on. In that same example you linked to, you can see the configuration in web.xml that binds all URLs ending with .vm (i.e. the pattern is *.vm) to the Velocity servlet, which is the one processing the templates. The request is then manually forwarded from the "main" servlet using the RequestDispatcher to the Velocity servlet by specifying a *.vm URL.